# WP_Query returns images but post_per_page is incorrect

Tags: wp-query

I have a working wp_query for a category returning images. My dev site seems to work fine. On the live site its returning way more than 6, and some that are not even the most recent post from that category. What looks to be incorrect in my wp_query?

Thank you -

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array(  'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ); ?>

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

      <?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post_mime_type' => 'image',  'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID );
      $images = get_posts( $args );
      if ( $images ) {
          foreach ( $images as $image ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><div class="gamecam-pic"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID , 'medium' ); ?>" rel="lightbox"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'gamecam img-responsive' ); ?></a></div></div>
      <?php   }
} ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif;

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: You should indent your code correctly and place 1 statement per line. I suspect this is related to your use of `$post` and not placing a `global` statement anywhere. I'd also move the reset postdata call inside the if statement so that it only cleans up if there's something to be cleaned up

Comment: I moved the reset inside of the if statement, still responding different on my live site for some reason. The standard loop for the posts per page via the reading settings on the dashboard does not reflect accurately. I am assuming it as to do with creating a **global** statement. I am am not understanding the difference from reading the codex on **global** and **$post** query.

Comment: the reset statement isn't a solution to your problem, but it is still a problem in its own right, I mention it for completeness. Re: `global`, global variables in PHP can't just be used, you need to tell PHP that you intend to use them with a statement, e.g. `global $post;`

Comment: I seem to have it working now other than the wp_reset_postdata is not resetting the default loop. My posts_per_page via the admin is not working. It is only showing 3 posts like my custom wp_query does. See the attached pastebin for full code on my index.php template http://pastebin.com/Qw4Hnmj4